# Loop through rows in Excel and do some logical comparisons

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with many columns and rows in it. The data has a header row. I need to process each row individually, look at a specific column, pull that value (a mnemonic), look at it and "Do Something" based on that value (Logical comparisons and stuff).

I just need the best way to set up the looping so It starts at the first non-header row and looks at my value and do some comparisons. The comparison logic I can do. It is the row-walking I am unfamiliar with in VBA.

Any down and dirty, quicky solutions?

Comment: This is not how Stack Overflow works. You come here with a specific programming problem. You show us what you have tried and what didn't work and then we help you get it to work. We do not write code for people, if that's for you're looking for hire a freelancer ;)

Comment: Take a look at the "Related" links (further down this page, on the right). There are good examples in those questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that scans down column **B** starting at row **2** looking for "Happiness":

```
Sub Happiness()
    Dim N As Long, I As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For I = 2 To N
        If Cells(I, "B").Value = "Happiness" Then
            MsgBox "Found happiness"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next I
    MsgBox "Failed"
End Sub
```